# codeigniter test sending mails on windows

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, codeigniter-2

i am currently developing a website which requires email verification, but i am developing on windows, and would like to test sending email verifications on localhost. I tried using Test Mail Server Tool, but i don't think i am setting it up correctly because there were no errors, but i didn't receive any email. this is the code i put in my config file

`$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$config['charset'] =  'utf-8';

$config['mailpath'] = 'C:\Program Files\Toolheap\Test Mail Server Tool\TestMailServerTool.exe'; 

$config['protocol']= 'smtp';`

what am i doing wrong? i am really new to this so i have no idea where to start looking.
i created an email.php and put that in application/config/ so i don't think i need to initialize it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether or not you need to include the following configuration options?

- smtp_host
- smtp_user
- smtp_pass
- smtp_port